# Android usb host serial communication with custom made board

Tags: java, android, xml, usb

I'm working with an android 4.0.3 tablet. I need it to communicate with a custom made board via USB serial at 9600 baud rate. The custom board's usb port allows serial connection. I was wondering of someone can point me in the direction on how i can get my application on my tablet to send and receive some information between the two. All the help is appreciated.

Dogz1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use USB Host API for doing this. The API documentation explain how to use the USB Host API, step by step in the official documentation page here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

Also if you are working with something like an Arduino Board, and if your board has USB host capability, I would recomment using [ADK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) for communication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The USB Host API looks good for what I want but I have another question. In the API it says that the android app must obtain permission to communicate with my board. What kind of information is communicated? The reason I ask this is because all the board is doing is sending and receiving a packet of 58 bytes to and from the android tablet. Do I have to set up my board so that i sends something for this permission?

Comment: No no, permission is for your android application. Nothing to do on the board side.

Comment: Thanks for your help, was able to get permission and both end points